# Use bash script to extract info from html

Tags: html, bash, url, extract, spreadsheet

I'm a novice programmer currently messing around with java. I had an idea for a program that a friend told me would be best executed in bash but I don't have time to learn another programming language. Basically, I want it to ask for a url, then go to that url and extract info between tags that I specify (using regular expressions, of course), then put that info in an excel spreadsheet.

Comment: Parsing HTML with a bash script is a classic *don't do it*-example - it's unreliable and you have to account for the many ways of expressing something in HTML (and what about frames and scripting that can change the document?). If you really want to do it this way, then do post more details, like what tags you're looking for.

Comment: You don't want to parse xml using regular expressions. regular expressions quickly become a nightmare if most of the logic is based on that. Using a library to parse xml is better. 
That said if you have only one very specific request maybe scripting it can be fun.

Answer (score 2):

you should look at xmllint if on Mac; xmlstarlet for Unix flavors.  I've used both for similar shell scripts before and it does a great job.

for example

```
wget target_url -q -O - > test.html
xmlstarlet sel -t -c "!doctype/html/collection/item[property=1234]" test.html
```

might yield something like

```
<item>
  <foo>hello</foo>
  <baz>world</baz>
  <property>1234</property>
</item>
```

you'd have to know your doc tree to explore down to the tag your are searching for 'collection/item' is just an example.

if you want real power in html scraping check Python with BeatifulSoup, but that would be overkill in this case

Answer (score 1):

use curl url > out.txt, then use grep regex out.txt (which gets the lines including the regex). As the comment said above you may want to use a real programming language depending on what you want to extract because bash is very unreliable.

Answer (score 1):

While I agree that parsing html in bash is generally a bad idea, if this is a one off it may be worth while.

For example, this gets the title tag from a given URL:

```
wget --no-check-certificate --quiet -O - http://someurl.com \
| paste -sd ' ' - \
| grep -o -e '<head[^>]*>.*</head>' \
| grep -o -e '<title>.*</title>' \
| cut -d '>' -f 2 \
| cut -d '<' -f 1 \
| tr -d '   ' \
| sed 's| *\(.*\)|\1|g' \
| paste -s -d '\n' -
```

There are an almost infinite number of ways this can go wrong (title tags are not exact, multiple title tags). In the specific case I'm using it in, its a one-off that is going to be reviewed by humans anyway.

If you are new to BASH, this may give you an idea of the commands you need to read up on to get started. If you know Java, write it in that.